# Google Maps API V3 Invalid Key

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou com o seguinte erro em meu site conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: Imagem]

Já criei a chave da API e nada, não sei o que pode ter ocorrido.

Meu site é http://mdesign.ppg.br/2015/mdesign

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Aconselho a dar uma olhada no tour http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e que formule sua pergunta de forma mais sucinta.

Comment: Tenta ir no [Developers Console](http://console.developers.google.com) e ver se a tua API está ativa na sessão APIs e Autenticação.

Comment: Já está ativa JefSilva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido! Eu deixei sem nenhum referenciador nas opções Credenciais.

Answer (score 0):

Como o próprio erro informa:

> Chave inválida ou não autorizada

Verificando a chamada do seu script, você esqueceu de adicionar o parâmetro identificando a API: **?v=3**

Troque o:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC0N5vxgEB5DM0S5kASQnR1clYdKgU4HUU&amp;sensor=false"></script>
```

Por:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyC0N5vxgEB5DM0S5kASQnR1clYdKgU4HUU&amp;sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: Eu fiz a alteração no script, mas o erro ainda continua :/